# How to make youtube videos to stay in line(ul>li)?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a Youtube gallery(responsive as well) in which my videos would stay next to each other. I have tried to put them in a container, and make an unordered list, but it still stays vertical. Any ideas maybe? Thanks for all the help!

Here is my css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {width: 200px;}
    .container ul li {display: inline block;}
</style>
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
    <li><iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kG_QhttG6jo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
    <li><iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kG_QhttG6jo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
    <li><iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kG_QhttG6jo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
    <li><iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kG_QhttG6jo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container width is only 200px so the videos are being forced to stack vertically. Try changing your CSS to this:

```
.container {
  width: auto;
}

.container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Yes i did notice that, but when I make it so it just stretches each video from one margin to the other, and keeps them vertical...

Comment: in addition to this, try setting your iframe to an explicit width with css.

Comment: Tried, still get the same result... My text editor didn't even recognize the explicit attribute(Sublime text 2)

Comment: I think you're changing the wrong width. The container is the width for all of your content on the page. Your iframe width is the width of the youtube videos you're embedding. Make sure you're changing the CSS style sheet and not the iframe width from 200px.

See here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPrjOb

Comment: ^Also he didn't mean explicit as a tag, he meant set an exact width (ex. 200px)

Comment: Oh I fell so stupid. Somehow my "-" from the inline-block got deleted, so it didn't accept the attribute. Works great. Thanks a lot guys, these tips mean the world for a newbie like me :)